# Select <svg> root of Fragment with Snap.svg

Tags: javascript, svg, snap.svg

In Snap.svg I load an external SVG file and after I append it to the document, I must change some of its attributes and contents.
I want to set the `x` and `y` attributes of the  element which is the root element of the Fragment `d`. `d.select("svg")` returns null and the following code still doesn't work.

```
Snap.load("but1.svg", function (d) {
    s.append(d);
    d.attr({
        x: "50",
        y: "50"
    });
});
```

**Update:** `s` is the Paper instance.

Comment: what if you make it: s.attr(... Does that work?

Comment: I have updated my question. `s` is the Paper instance, it does not have an `attr` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can do it quite like that with a fragment. I think you would need to use a select to grab the element, an example (can't test without the svg file)..

```
Snap.load("but1.svg", function (d) {
    s.append(d);
    var el = s.select("#myElement");
    el.attr({
        x: "50",
        y: "50"
    });
});
```

Comment: The code I use now is: `var el = s.select("#svg2"); el.attr({ ... });`. "svg2" seems to be the ID that Snap.svg automatically puts on the second <svg> element appended to the document.

Comment: Actually, "svg2" is the ID that the SVG editor put in the SVG file on the root element <svg>. It is not related to Snap.svg.

Answer (score 1):

To build on Ian's answer, you can simply select the svg element from the fragment with `fragment.select('svg')` So the resulting pattern would be:

```
Snap.load('myGraphic.svg', function (fragment) {
    var element = fragment.select('svg');
    paper.add(element);
    element.attr({
        x: "50",
        y: "50"
    });
});
```